# Replace non-expanded to a expanded environment variable

Tags: bash, sed, environment-variables

I wanna create a script .sh that wget a file and then replace part of the text to another.
Part of the file that I will download:
`curl -s -S -l -u "${USER}:${PASSWORD}" /path --ftp-ssl -k >/dev/null`

I wanna replace it to:
`curl -s -S -l -u 'myuser':'mypassword' /path --ftp-ssl -k >/dev/null`

i.e., I wanna take double quotes off, put single quotes and replace ${USER} and ${PASSWORD} to values.

That's what I tried: `sed "s|"${USER}:${PASSWORD}"|'${MY_USER}':'${MY_PASSWORD}'|g"`

Problems:

- This command tries to expand ${USER} and ${PASSWORD}. I dont want it.
- I think that '${MY_USER}' and '${MY_PASSWORD}' dont expand to 'myuser' and 'mypassword' because of the simple quote, but I need then to expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the pattern to replace inside single quotes, so that `${USER}` and `${PASSWORD}` won't be replaced by the shell. You also need to escape the `$` in the regexp so they'll be matched literally rather than matching the end of the line.

Put the replacement inside single quotes, so the variables *will* be replaced.

```
sed 's|"\${USER}:\${PASSWORD}"|'"'${MY_USER}':'${MY_PASSWORD}'|g"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use sed for this you could get a cryptic failure depending on which characters `mypassword` actually contains because sed has no ability to work with literal strings. awk, on the other hand, understands literal strings:

```
$ MY_USER='myuser'
$ MY_PASSWORD='mypassword'
$ MY_USER="$MY_USER" MY_PASSWORD="$MY_PASSWORD" awk '
    BEGIN {
        old = "\"${USER}:${PASSWORD}\""
        new = "\047" ENVIRON["MY_USER"] "\047:\047" ENVIRON["MY_PASSWORD"] "\047"
    }
    s=index($0,old) { $0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old)) }
    { print }
' file
curl -s -S -l -u 'myuser':'mypassword' /path --ftp-ssl -k >/dev/null
```

sed will produce the same output with the above values of `MY_PASSWORD`:

```
$ sed 's|"\${USER}:\${PASSWORD}"|'"'${MY_USER}':'${MY_PASSWORD}'|g" file
curl -s -S -l -u 'myuser':'mypassword' /path --ftp-ssl -k >/dev/null
```

but let's try a few others:

```
$ MY_PASSWORD='foo|bar'

$ MY_USER="$MY_USER" MY_PASSWORD="$MY_PASSWORD" awk 'BEGIN{old="\"${USER}:${PASSWORD}\""; new="\047" ENVIRON["MY_USER"] "\047:\047" ENVIRON["MY_PASSWORD"] "\047"} s=index($0,old){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} {print}' file
curl -s -S -l -u 'myuser':'foo|bar' /path --ftp-ssl -k >/dev/null

$ sed 's|"\${USER}:\${PASSWORD}"|'"'${MY_USER}':'${MY_PASSWORD}'|g" file
sed: -e expression #1, char 41: unknown option to `s'
```

```
$ MY_PASSWORD='foo&bar'

$ MY_USER="$MY_USER" MY_PASSWORD="$MY_PASSWORD" awk 'BEGIN{old="\"${USER}:${PASSWORD}\""; new="\047" ENVIRON["MY_USER"] "\047:\047" ENVIRON["MY_PASSWORD"] "\047"} s=index($0,old){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} {print}' file
curl -s -S -l -u 'myuser':'foo&bar' /path --ftp-ssl -k >/dev/null

$ sed 's|"\${USER}:\${PASSWORD}"|'"'${MY_USER}':'${MY_PASSWORD}'|g" file
curl -s -S -l -u 'myuser':'foo"${USER}:${PASSWORD}"bar' /path --ftp-ssl -k >/dev/null
```

```
$ MY_PASSWORD=$'foo\nbar'

$ MY_USER="$MY_USER" MY_PASSWORD="$MY_PASSWORD" awk 'BEGIN{old="\"${USER}:${PASSWORD}\""; new="\047" ENVIRON["MY_USER"] "\047:\047" ENVIRON["MY_PASSWORD"] "\047"} s=index($0,old){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} {print}' file
curl -s -S -l -u 'myuser':'foo
bar' /path --ftp-ssl -k >/dev/null

$ sed 's|"\${USER}:\${PASSWORD}"|'"'${MY_USER}':'${MY_PASSWORD}'|g" file
sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unterminated `s' command
```

```
$ MY_PASSWORD='foo\1bar'

$ MY_USER="$MY_USER" MY_PASSWORD="$MY_PASSWORD" awk 'BEGIN{old="\"${USER}:${PASSWORD}\""; new="\047" ENVIRON["MY_USER"] "\047:\047" ENVIRON["MY_PASSWORD"] "\047"} s=index($0,old){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} {print}' file
curl -s -S -l -u 'myuser':'foo\1bar' /path --ftp-ssl -k >/dev/null

$ sed 's|"\${USER}:\${PASSWORD}"|'"'${MY_USER}':'${MY_PASSWORD}'|g" file
sed: -e expression #1, char 47: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

```
$ MY_PASSWORD='foo\tbar'

$ MY_USER="$MY_USER" MY_PASSWORD="$MY_PASSWORD" awk 'BEGIN{old="\"${USER}:${PASSWORD}\""; new="\047" ENVIRON["MY_USER"] "\047:\047" ENVIRON["MY_PASSWORD"] "\047"} s=index($0,old){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} {print}' file
curl -s -S -l -u 'myuser':'foo\tbar' /path --ftp-ssl -k >/dev/null

$ sed 's|"\${USER}:\${PASSWORD}"|'"'${MY_USER}':'${MY_PASSWORD}'|g" file
curl -s -S -l -u 'myuser':'foo  bar' /path --ftp-ssl -k >/dev/null
```

```
$ MY_PASSWORD='foo\\bar'

$ MY_USER="$MY_USER" MY_PASSWORD="$MY_PASSWORD" awk 'BEGIN{old="\"${USER}:${PASSWORD}\""; new="\047" ENVIRON["MY_USER"] "\047:\047" ENVIRON["MY_PASSWORD"] "\047"} s=index($0,old){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))} {print}' file
curl -s -S -l -u 'myuser':'foo\\bar' /path --ftp-ssl -k >/dev/null

curl -s -S -l -u 'myuser:foo\\bar' /path --ftp-ssl -k >/dev/null

$ sed 's|"\${USER}:\${PASSWORD}"|'"'${MY_USER}':'${MY_PASSWORD}'|g" file
curl -s -S -l -u 'myuser':'foo\bar' /path --ftp-ssl -k >/dev/null
```

Note that in every case awk replaces the old string with the new one as-is while sed fails, sometimes with a cryptic error message.

If you want to stick with sed you can add some code to sanitize your variables before calling sed, see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) for more information on how to make the sed script robust.

See [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for why/how I'm using `ENVIRON[]` in the awk script.